# Web Scraping with cheerio Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape the jobs with zero experience on [MonsterIndia.com](https://www.monsterindia.com), so i wrote the following code using cheerio and nodejs, i observed that i can search for `php` jobs by seaching it like `https://www.monsterindia.com/**php**-jobs.html` but if i want to search the php jobs with zero experience i had to add filters manually on the site, but it does not reflect in the url of the page, so how can i achieve this, i am a complete beginner in web scraping, please help.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
const context = "php";
function scraper(context){
    request('http://www.monsterindia.com/'+context+"-jobs.html", function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("Request Called");
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var jobs = [];
            var json = {title : "", link:"", description:"", };
            $('a.title_in').each(function(i , element){


                console.log($(this).attr('title'));

            })
        } 
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        } 

    });
}
scraper(context);
```

Comment: I'd look in the source for the page to see if there's an RSS feed. That would be easier than scraping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to use `.filter()` function in cheerio, following is my code which implements one such filters.

```
var job = $('div.job-container').filter(function (i, el) {
 var exp = $(this).children('div.view-apply- 
  container').children('div.padding-top-5').children('div.col-md- 
  3.col-xs-3.col-lg-3').children('span.experience');
  if (!exp){
      return $('div.job-container');
  }
  else{
      exp = exp.text().charAt(0) === '0';
      return exp;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [casperjs](http://casperjs.org/) library to achieving your aim. It is a simple example that are placed in its website to searching for a word using Google search engine and then fetching links that is placed in the first page of search result.

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute('href');
    });
}

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
   // Wait for the page to be loaded
   this.waitForSelector('form[action="/search"]');
});

casper.then(function() {
   // search for 'casperjs' from google form
   this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'casperjs' search
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
    // now search for 'phantomjs' by filling the form again
    this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'phantomjs' }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results for the 'phantomjs' search
    links = links.concat(this.evaluate(getLinks));
});

casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Comment: How can i use it to get the jobs filtered as with experience as 0 years, because like imdb, the filters are not reflected in the url, so have to do it by some get or post request, and as far as i get it, you're using casper.js  to fetch links, which i don't want.

Comment: You should fill input texts, like above example:    
   `this.fill('form[action="/search"]', { q: 'casperjs' }, true);`

Comment: for a detailed example, you can use this: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#click